# Logistic Equation: Find K

Tags: calculus

How do I solve for K, the carrying capacity, in the logistic equation (check below)? Sorry, if the equation I wrote is hard to read, anyways, it should be easy to find online. I have no idea how to solve for K and I need help on it. Thank you.

Comment: Welcome to the website. Look [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) for a basic guide on Mathjax to be able to format your equations.

Comment: Is this $$P(t)=\frac{K}{(1+\frac{K-V_0}{V_0})e^{rt}}$$